# Wordpress posts page

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress, I'm using ver 3.9 but I found that no page is listing posts. only with the default theme they show up as a little menu of recent posts. how to make the front page list all the posts with excerpts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create your Blog Page and then assign all post to that page

**Step 1** : Create Page Blog

**Step 2** : Go to Setting -> Reading -> Front page displays -> Post Page -> Blog

[image]

Answer (score 1):

WordPress uses a [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

If you create a file called `front-page.php` in your theme then this template will be used for both *Your latest posts* and *A static page* (these are set in the 'Front page displays' section of Settings > Reading).

You can also use `home.php` as the template for *Your latest posts*.

**Note:** If you are using 'A static front page' then the static front page takes precedence over your list of blog posts. Therefore `example.com` will show your static page and `example.com/my-blog` will display your list of blog posts (*my-blog* is the slug of your blog posts page).